# Test for list membership and get index at the same time in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, idioms

It seems silly to write the following:

```
L = []

if x in L:
  L[x] = something
else:
  L[x] = something_else
```

Doesn't this perform the look-up for x twice?  I tried using index(), but this gives an error when the value is not found.

Ideally I would like to say like:

```
if x is in L, save that index and:
  ...
```

I can appreciate that this might be a beginner python idiom, but it seems rather un-search-able. Thanks.

Comment: You're using a dictionary, they don't have indexes or ordering like a list does.

Comment: The title says list, I assume the dictionary is a typo

Comment: You're question had some sense with a dictionary. Now it's just pointless...

Comment: It is rather a mess isn't it? Unfortunately I can't delete it, so I tried to salvage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is try/except:

```
d = {}
try:
    d[x] = something_else
except KeyError:
    d[x] = something
```

Same result as your code.

Edit: Okay, fast moving target. Same idiom for a list, different exception (IndexError).

Comment: `d[x] = something_else` will never generate KeyError. It will just assign/overwrite the value. KeyError is generated when retrieving the value, not setting it.

Comment: I agree with @warvariuc. No KeyError Exception will be raised there for a dict type.

Comment: Also the something_else should be beneath the `except`.  AND if that example was a list where `L = []` you would get an exception again in the `except` clause because `L[x]` would still raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want `setdefault(key[, default])`

```
a = {}
a['foo'] # KeyError
a.setdefault('foo', 'bar') # key not exist, set a['foo'] = 'bar'
a.setdefault('foo', 'x') # key exist, return 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *list* you can use `index`, catching the `ValueError` if it is thrown:

```
yourList = []
try:
    i = yourList.index(x)
except ValueError:
    i = None
```

Then you can test the value of i:

```
if i is not None:
    # Do things if the item was found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question confused many because you've mixed your syntax between dict and list.
If:

```
L = []  # L is synonym for list and [] (braces) used to create list()
```

Here you are looking for a value in a list, **not** a key nor a value in a dict:

```
if x in L:
```

And then you use **x** seemingly intended as a key but in lists it's an int() index and doing `if x in L:` doesn't test to see if index is in L but if value is in L:

```
L[x]=value
```

So if you intend to see if a value is in `L` a list do:

```
L = []                # that's a list and empty; and x will NEVER be in an empty list.
if x in L:            # that looks for value in list; not index in list
                      # to test for an index in a list do if len(L)>=x
   idx = L.index(x)
   L[idx] = something   # that makes L[index]=value not L[key]=value
else:
   # x is not in L so you either append it or append something_else
   L.append(x)
```

If you use:
`L[x] = something` together with `if x in L:` then it would make sense to have a list with only these values:  `L=[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` OR `L=[ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...]`

But I'd offer this:

```
L = []
L.extend(my_iterable)
coder0 = 'farr'
coder1 = 'Mark Byers'
if coder0 not in L:
    L.append(coder1)
```

Weird logic